# I want to decide the array sizing in a method, however my array needs to be public... How would I do this?

Tags: java, arrays

Currently, the array sizes are only 0. How would I change it so that my arrays stay public, but the sizing of the array can be changed in a method? The array needs to be public as it has to be accessed in other methods.

```
public class Array {

public int sizeArray;

public String mainArray [] = new String [sizeArray];

 public String halfArray[] = new String [sizeArray/2];

public void arraySizeManipulate () {

String line = ""; 

int x = -1;

try {
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("File.txt"));
  while (line != null)
  {
    line = r.readLine ();
    x++;
  }
  r.close ();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  System.out.println (e);
}
sizeArray = x;
}
}
```

Comment: consider formatting your code properly. at least that could shed some light on your question.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I'm new to this, so I'm not exactly sure how to format it..

Comment: it's being edited anyway, it's alright.

Comment: 1: no, no field should be public, but it's irrelevant 2. initialize the arrays after you know their size, not before (i.e. in the method).

Comment: @Sandy i think you need to change array size because you want to store a file content into that array is it true.

Comment: @javafan yes, the array size depends on how many lines there are in the file.

Comment: So its simple first loop through the file to get number of lines in the file and after you got it then declare your array.

Comment: @javafan it gives an error if I put the try block at the top (public)

Comment: i just added the answer

Comment: @javafan it errors because an array cannot be declared without the array dimensions

Comment: @Sandy edited my answer there is no error

Comment: @Sandy before it was wrong but just now i have compiled it.

Comment: @javafan it works now! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code which you need

```
    public class Array {

    public int sizeArray;
    //we will not declare the array right at this point because we don't know the file size or in general the value of sizeArray varable.
    public String mainArray [] ;

     public String halfArray[] ;

    public void arraySizeManipulate () {

    String line = ""; 

    int x = -1;

    try {
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("File.txt"));
      while (line != null)
      {
        line = r.readLine ();
        x++;
      }
      r.close ();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println (e);
    }
  //here x contains the  no of lines in the file 
 sizeArray = x;
//now global array get declared using the variable  size array.
 mainArray=new String[sizeArray];
    halfArray = new String [sizeArray/2];

    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: @JoeC i have edited my answer hope it might help other people

Answer (score 0):

Simple version of your class , by following the standards of java(You shouldn't create the fields public, instead use the getters and setters for the private fields). For simplicity i am accepting the size in the constructor and shown how to do it for `mainarray`.

```
public class ArraySo {

    private int sizeArray;

    ArraySo(int sizeArray){
        this.sizeArray = sizeArray;
    }

    private String mainArray [];// = new String [sizeArray];

    private String halfArray[]; //// = new String [sizeArray/2];

    public String[] getMainArray(){
        return mainArray = new String [sizeArray];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArraySo arraySo = new ArraySo(10);
        System.out.println(arraySo.getMainArray().length);
        //System.out.println(arraySo.halfArray.length);
    }

}
```